# Select many-to-many relations and pass it to json objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables

```
events:
   id
   title
   content
   status
   creator = ForeignKey(users.c.id)
   location_id = ForeignKey(locations.c.id)
   activities_id  = ForeignKey(activities.c.id)
   ....
   
users:
   id
   ...
   
accounts:
   id
   user_id = ForeignKey(users.c.id)
   name
   surname

location:
   id
   city
   street

 activities:
   id
   name
   
event_users
   id
   events_id = ForeignKey(events.c.id)
   users_id = ForeignKey(users.c.id)
```

#### What I'm trying to do

There is an activity (table `events`). The event has a creator (table `users`) associated with the `accounts` table. The event also has participants (table `events_user`). I need to pull information on the event, data on its creator (name and surname) and data on the participants of the event (also name and surname) in one query.
And I use the JSON object representation for easy further processing of the result.

#### What I've got

I have now been able to retrieve information except partiсipation user data

```
SELECT
    events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('city', locations.city, 'street', locations.street)) -> 0)AS location,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name)) -> 0) AS activity,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('name', accounts.name, 'surname', accounts.surname)) -> 0) AS creator
FROM
    events
JOIN
    locations ON events.location_id=locations.id
JOIN
    activities ON events.activities_id=activities.id
JOIN
    accounts ON events.creator=accounts.user_id
WHERE events.id = :pk GROUP BY events.id
```

**result**

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'fffffff', 'creator': '{"name" : Name, "surname" : SUrname}', 'content': 'dddddddddddddd', 'status': 'OPEN', 'location': '{"city" : "Warsaw", "street" : "jezewskiego"}', 'activity': '{"id" : 1, "name" : "baskeball"}'}
```

However, I can't figure out how I can add a many-to-many (link tables `events_users` and `accounts` as `members`) here to get something like

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'fffffff', 'creator': '{"name" : Name, "surname" : Surname}', 'content': 'dddddddddddddd', 'status': 'OPEN', 'location': '{"city" : "Warsaw", "street" : "jezewskiego"}', 'activity': '{"id" : 1, "name" : "baskeball"}', 'members': ['{"id": 1, "name" : Name1, "surname" : Surname1}, {"id": 2, "name" : Name2, "surname" : Surname2}']}
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.5 (Ubuntu 13.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use subquery on `events_user` and `accounts` tables then do `JOIN` and `json_agg` function.

```
SELECT
    events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('city', locations.city, 'street', locations.street)) -> 0)AS location,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name)) -> 0) AS activity,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('name', a.name, 'surname', a.surname)) -> 0) AS creator,
    json_agg(json_build_object('id', a.user_id, 'name', a.name, 'surname', a.surname)) members
FROM
    events
INNER JOIN
    locations ON events.location_id=locations.id
INNER JOIN
    activities ON events.activities_id=activities.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT events_id AS id, 
          a.user_id,
          a.name,
          a.surname
  FROM events_user e
  INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.user_id = e.users_id
) a ON a.id = events.id
WHERE events.id = :pk 
GROUP BY events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=64eaa58a2150df47d1e028e2850ab175)

**Edit**

if your `events_user` table will be empty, your can try to use `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` then use `CASE WHEN` to judgment `events_user` whether be empty.

```
SELECT
    events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('city', locations.city, 'street', locations.street)) -> 0)AS location,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('id', activities.id, 'name', activities.name)) -> 0) AS activity,
    (json_agg(json_build_object('name', a.name, 'surname', a.surname)) -> 0) AS creator,
    case when count(t1.user_id) = 0 then '[]' else json_agg(json_build_object('id', t1.user_id, 'name', t1.name, 'surname', t1.surname)) end  members
FROM
    events
INNER JOIN
    locations ON events.location_id=locations.id
INNER JOIN
    activities ON events.activities_id=activities.id
INNER JOIN 
    accounts a ON  events.creator=a.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT events_id AS id, 
          a.user_id,
          a.name,
          a.surname
  FROM events_user e
  INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.user_id = e.users_id
) t1 ON t1.id = events.id
WHERE events.id = :pk 
GROUP BY events.id, events.title, events.creator, events.content, events.status
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf0bed36a0c931981d45983172b94efa)

Comment: that seems to be exactly what I need. Only one thing, if `events_user` table is empty, i.e. there are no event participants, then the whole query returns empty. How can I make it possible for `members` to have an empty list if there are no participants?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=749bf4be45826ffd6c83629047191501

Comment: @Jekson I edit my answer you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Lateral joins come in handy when dealing with JSON or XML.

I usually retrieve the data I need from the various tables in lateral queries. For example :

```
SELECT events.id, events.title, creatorlateral.creator, memberslateral.members
FROM events
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT user_id, json_build_object('id', accounts.user_id, 'name', accounts.name, 'surname', accounts.surname)
  FROM accounts
) creatorlateral(user_id, creator) ON creatorlateral.user_id = events.creator
NATURAL JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT events_id AS id, json_agg(json_build_object('id', accounts.user_id, 'name', accounts.name, 'surname', accounts.surname))
  FROM events_user
  INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.user_id = events_user.users_id
  GROUP BY events_id
) memberslateral(id, members)
```

Note that you don't need json_agg when retrieving a single row.

Essentially:

- We retrieve the creator in JSON format in the creatorlateral join, along with a user_id column to be able to join.
- We retrieve the members in JSON format in the memberslateral join, for each events_id, along with the events_id column to be able to join. To ease things I used a NATURAL JOIN and renamed the events_id column to id, so that the join is made on the column id in each join side.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f3dd675aa2a8823cbed6e80aa5c9de47

Comment: I got `column "creatorlateral.creator" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: This query runs without error on my machine :-S
I added a link to a dbfiddle in the answer.

Comment: I apologise for not writing that correctly. In my query the `id` of the event is determined by the pk parameter in the WHERE condition , if I use your query unchanged I get `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'pk'`

Comment: the previous error is the result of my experiments with adding a WHERE condition